# Java project import into eclipse created a broken hierarchy of folders

Tags: eclipse, import, project-structure

I imported a Java project into Eclipse workspace and the structure of the project folders broke. Attached the screenshot of the situation. How to safely import a project with out breaking the structure of the project.

The second image shows how the project looks on a file system. Won't eclipse displays the hierarchy in the similar fashion visually in the left pane.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Explain what you think is "broken" about the "structure." I see compilation errors, but those aren't related to any folder structure. Also, what version and package of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: Am using Eclipse Luna version. In the left pane, the folder structures are not organized properly. My question is not about the errors or warnings, sorry for not framing the question properly with additional details.

Comment: To echo the first comment, explain what you think is wrong with it.  This is how a conventional Java project should look.

Comment: Note that the source being in 'src/main/java' and the presence of a 'pom.xml' means this is a Maven project which is structured differently to a plain Java project.